# DSum function for a matching key, with 3 Criteria

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm trying a DSum function, with 3 arguments to sum a particular field (field_to_sum) from a table (Tablesource), ensuring that it will only sum up the records where the table key is equal to the key record loaded on my form.

My function continues to return error.
I appreciate some help

Here is my function

=DSum("[field_to_sum], "["*","table_1","ID = " & [ID] & "] AND [field_1] <> 'DESIST' AND [field_2] = 'NO' AND IsNull(field_3)=true")

Answer (score 0):

Finally right

DSum("field_to_sum ","table_1","[ID]= " & [ID] & "AND [field_1] <> 'DESIST' AND [fiels_2] = 'NO' AND IsNull(field_3)=true")